# About the array theory in Z3

Tags: arrays, z3

I want to know, if I can make Z3 'remember' the update of an array.

For example, the following input is satisfiable:

```
(declare-const x Int)
(declare-const a1 (Array Int Int))
(assert  (= (select (store a1 x 2) x) 2))
(assert (not (= (select a1 x) 2)))
(check-sat)
```

The 'store' in the first assertion does not affect the second assertion.
Can I make the store operation on the array resulting eternal change on the array?
I mean, if I use store on an array, for then, the array is changed forever.
e.g., if after I use '(store a1 x 2)', then, every time (select a1 x) is equal to 2.
Anybody know this?
Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The expression `(= (select (store a1 x 2) x) 2)` is equivalent to `true`. It is a vacuous assertion, since one of the array theory axioms is `forall a,i,v: select(store(a,i,v), i) = v`. Thus, this expression is just an instance of the axiom (which is built-in in Z3), and for this reason it is redundant.

Perhaps, you intended to assert `(assert (= (select a1 x) 2))`. This assertion says the the value of the array at position `x` is `2`. That is, any solution produced by Z3 will have to assign `2` to this position of the array `a1`.

Note that, there is no notion of "before" and "after" an assertion, or side-effects in Z3.
For example, the expression `a = a + 1` is equivalent to `false` in Z3. One common technique used to encode programming language assignments into Z3 uses multiples variables for each program variable. One variable for each "program location". For example, the code block `a = a + 1; b = 2*a; a = b + 1` is encoded as `a_1 = a_0 + 1 and b_1 = 2*a_0 and a_2 = b_1 + 1`.
The following article contains more examples/details: http://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=1995394

If you intend to encode an array update used in a program, you should have one array `a1` representing the array before the update, and one array `a2` representing the array after the update.
That is, we write: `(assert (= a2 (store a1 x 2)))`, and replace the last assertion with (assert `(not (= (select a2 x) 2)))`